# Approximation of the variance of the first order statistic (min) of normal random variates

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, order-statistics

I'm looking for a closed form approximation of the variance of the minimum order statistic for normal random variates. Can anyone point me to a reference, or an approximation?

I've seen the post about the approximate expected value of the min order statistic ([Approximate order statistics for normal random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/approximate-order-statistics-for-normal-random-variables)), but I'm looking for the variance. Thanks!

Comment: Note that by exploiting symmetry you can also take advantage of any results on the maximum.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610919908813542) may be of some value