# In R, what does qqnorm actually do?

Tags: r, qq-plot

```
qqnorm(x)
plot(qnorm(seq(80)/81),sort(x))
```

Finding that the plots produced by the commands above are slightly different from each other, I tried this:

```
qqnorm(qnorm(seq(80)/81))
```

I got a slightly less than perfect line.  I'd have tried regressing the result of `qnorm(seq(80)/81)` on the variable that was plotted on the $x$-axis and plotting residuals against the predictor, expecting to see some graceful curve, but for the fact that I don't know what to use as the predictor.  Possibly such a residual plot would reveal more than just the graceful S-shaped thing I'd anticipate.

So my question is this: if the thing on the $x$-axis in the plot produced by `qqnorm` is *not* what I get from `qnorm(seq(80)/81)` (and what I did shows that indeed it is not), then what is it?

Comment: One other thing I could imagine it might be is the _expected values_ of the standard normal order statistics.  But I don't know an efficient way to compute those or any standard commands to get them, unless that's what I actually get from qqnorm. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This seems to be a question about R code, not the nature of qq-plots themselves. If this is actually a statistical question, please edit it to make that aspect more obvious.

Comment: See the help page for `ppoints`, as referenced in that for `qqnorm`.

Comment: As Scortchi suggests, the precise details of how the quantiles are calculated are in `ppoints`. They're not quite expected quantiles, but the use of a=3/8 for n<10 is a good approximation suggested by Blom(1958); I am not sure why the function changes to a=1/2 above that but it only makes visually noticeable difference at the two extreme points and for n past about 30 or so not even then.

Comment: See [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/approximate-order-statistics-for-normal-random-variables) and also [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pAsQd.png) of expected normal order statistics against Blom's approximation for n=10 with a line through $O$ with slope 1 in red.

Answer (score 5):

Based on comments above and pages to which they link, it appears that the command

```
ppoints(seq(80))
```

gives us this:

\begin{align}
& \left( \frac{1}{2\cdot 80},\ \frac{3}{2\cdot 80},\ \frac{5}{2\cdot 80},\ \frac{7}{2\cdot 80},\ \ldots,\ \frac{159}{2\cdot 80} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} &\left( \ldots,\ \frac{2i-1}{2\cdot 80},\ \ldots : i=1,\ldots,80  \right) \tag 1
\end{align}
and

```
qnorm(ppoints(seq(80)))
```

gives us precisely what is plotted on the $x$-axis when one uses the command

```
qqnorm(x)
```

where $x$ is a vector with $80$ components.

My first guess had been that instead of $(1)$ we would have
\begin{align}
& \left( \frac 1 {81},\ \frac 2 {81},\ \frac 3 {81},\ \ldots,\ \frac{80}{81} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( \ldots,\ \frac i {80+1},\ \ldots\  : i=1,\ldots 80 \right).
\end{align}