# Principal component analysis and DBScan

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, dbscan

My data has 30 dimensions and 150 observations.
I want to cluster the data with DBScan. 
Is there a difference between:
 1. Performing a PCA and clustering all 30 principal components or
 2. Just clustering the raw data?

DBScan works fast on my small dataset. Should I reduce the dimensions anyway? Is dimension reduction only about speed?

Comment: A PCA is going to help you interpret the clusters found by your clustering method. I don't think that the results of DBScan will be different if you apply it to the raw data or to the 30 principal components (but I could be wrong). Applying it only to the first 2 components will probably give different results. Also, on the kind of data that you have, you may want to consider a hierarchical clustering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) has many different facets and one of them is that in high-dimensional domain finding relevant neighbours becomes hard. That is due to qualitative as well as quantitative reasons.

Qualitative, it becomes difficult to have a reasonable metric of similarity. As different dimensions are not necessarily comparable, what constitutes an appropriate "distance" become ill-defined.

Quantitative, even when a distance is well defined, the expected Euclidean distance between any two neighbouring points gets increasingly large. In a high dimensional problem, the data are sparse and as a result local neighbourhoods contain very few points. That is the reason why high-dimensional density estimation is a notoriously hard problem. As a rule of thump, density estimation tends to become quite difficult above 4-5 dimensions - 30 is a definite overkill.

Returning to DBSCAN: In DBSCAN, through the concepts of `eps` and `neighbourhood` we try to define regions of "high density". This task is prone to provide spurious results when the number of dimensions in a sample is high. Even if we assume a relatively well-behaved sample uniformly distributed in $[0,1]^d$, the average distance between points increases by $\sqrt{d}$. See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233931) too; it deals with Gaussian data in a similar "curse of dimensionality" situation.

I attach a small R quick script showing how the expected distance between points in $U[0,1]^d$ increases with $d$. Notice that the individual features of our multi-dimensional sample $Z$ only take values in $[0,1]$ but the expected distance quickly jumps to values above $2$ after $d = 25$:

```
set.seed(11)
N = 1234;
d <- round(seq(2,333, length.out = 33)) 

# 20-30" execution time 
averageDist <- sapply(d, function(myd){ 
  set.seed(myd)
  Z = matrix( ncol = myd, data = runif(N*myd) ); 
  mean( dist(Z) )
})

cor(averageDist , sqrt(d))
# 0.9999903

par(mar=c(5,5,4,2))
plot(averageDist, x = d, panel.first = grid(), 
     ylab = expression("Expected distance between points in U[0,1]"^{d}),
     t='l', xlab= "# of dimensions (d) ")
```

[image]

So, yes, it is advisable to reduce the dimensionality of a sample before using a clustering algorithm like DBSCAN that relies on notion of sample density.
Performing PCA or another dimensional reduction algorithm (e.g. [NNMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) if applicable) would be a good idea. Dimensional reduction is not merely a "speed issue" but also a methodological one that has repercussions both in the relevancy of our analysis as well as the feasibility of it.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you for your time! Is there any rule about the number of features to get after reducing dimension for dbscan? Like`F(x=amount of features) == n=reasonable amount of features`

Comment: There is no such rule off the top of my head.