# Find a limiting distribution using mgf

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, convergence, moment-generating-function

Say you have normally distributed iid random variables, $X_1, X_2,....,X_n$ with with known mean and variance.  And you wanted to find the limiting distribution of one of these

$Y_n = max\{X_1, X_2,....,X_n\}$ or $T_n = min\{X_1, X_2,....,X_n\}$

Is it possible to find the limiting distribution with using the mgf of the normally distributed random variables?  If so, how does one go about it or is this a bad tactic?

I can find only a general example or two using the uniform distribution.

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236464/determine-the-limiting-distribution-of-standard-normal-order-statistics/304396#304396

Comment: To calculate the mgf of the max of n iid normals seem hopeless, there are better methods ...