# How to derive the fi formula (i−.375)/(n+.25) used in expected Z-score

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, z-score

I have encoutnered this formula used to calcualte cumulative probabilty based on the number of samples:

$$fi = \frac{i-3/8}{n+1/4}$$

some website uses the decimal form:
$$fi = \frac{i-0.375}{n+0.25}$$

My question is how does one derive this formula?

One reference is here https://brownmath.com/ti83/nchk89.htm#Theory

Comment: Can you add some references, where you found  this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've seen those formulas in [plotting positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot#Heuristics) in a Q-Q-plot.

Comment: It is based empirically on finding *plotting points* for a normal QQ plot that tend to work well, even at the extremes, for genuinely Normal data.

Comment: A reference for the formula $\frac{i-\alpha}{n+1-2\alpha}$ (here with $\alpha=\frac38$) is Blom, G. (1958), Statistical estimates and transformed beta variables, New York: John Wiley and Sons

Comment: There's some excellent answers on a related question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/approximate-order-statistics-for-normal-random-variables (and indeed on a number of other questions on site). The Blom formula (not always with the same $\alpha$) is also used for other distributions but that discussion of the normal covers the main considerations.